# Stuff() two datetime columns into a comma-separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this two records and I want to stuff the date together in SQL server.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1
(
SALE_DT DATETIME,
ID INT
)
INSERT INTO #TEMP1 VALUES ('1/12/2011 12:00 AM','12345')
INSERT INTO #TEMP1 VALUES ('3/11/2011 12:00 AM','12345')
```

when I tried the query below, I have a "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

```
SELECT
STUFF(ISNULL((SELECT ', ' + X.SALE_DT 
FROM #TEMP1 X WHERE X.ID = T.ID
GROUP BY X.SALE_DT FOR XML PATH ('')), ''), 1, 2, '') AS DATES
FROM #TEMP1 T
```

and when I tried the query below, I was able to stuff the date but the result was not what I wanted

```
SELECT DISTINCT
STUFF(ISNULL((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, X.SALE_DT) 
FROM #TEMP1 X WHERE X.ID = T.ID
GROUP BY X.SALE_DT FOR XML PATH ('')), ''), 1, 2, '') AS DATES,
ID
FROM #TEMP1 T
```

I wanted my result like:

```
SALE_DT              ID
1/12/2011, 3/11/2011 12345
```

Comment: _"the result was not what I wanted"_ What was it, then? What problem are you trying to solve? If the result is being stored anywhere, it seems like a bad design. If it is only being presented, then maybe the frontend is a better place to do this.

Comment: @ underscore, it was Jan 12 2011 12:00AM, Mar 11 2011 12:00AM 12345

Comment: Change your convert function to `CONVERT(CHAR(10), X.SALE_DT, 103)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
SELECT ID,
        STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), X.SALE_DT) 
                FROM #TEMP1 X
                WHERE X.ID = T.ID
                FOR XML PATH ('')
               ), 1, 2, ''
             ) AS DATES
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM #TEMP1 T) T;
```

Notes:

- Always provide a length to `VARCHAR` in SQL Server.  The default length varies by context and might not belong enough.
- Based on your sample data, you don't need a `GROUP BY` in the subquery.  I'm more inclined to use `SELECT DISTINCT` in this case, but they do the same thing.
- Similarly, I see no reason to replace a `NULL` value with an empty string.  You can, of course, use `COALESCE()` if you really want to avoid `NULL`.
- Doing the `SELECT DISTINCT ID` in a subquery should be a performance optimization -- the subquery is run only once per `id`.
- The `VARCHAR(10)` only brings back the date, in whatever internationalization setting you have.  You should probably be using `FORMAT()` or an explicit conversion code.

Comment: Thanks ALL. I actually convert the sale_dt first before I stuffed. example: convert (varchar (10), sale_dt, 101) as sale_dt. The rest is history. Thanks for the idea!